# Microsoft Dynamics 2011 Async Service Error at Startup

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, trace

I have a Microsoft Dynamics installation that works fine. However, I noticed that even though it is functioning fine, two errors are written to the event log whenever the CRM async service is started:

`CrmTrace encountered an error. Additional Info:Error in LoadSiteWideSettings [LocatorService.Instance], Stack Trace :    at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmTraceSettings.Load(String traceDirectory)
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmTrace.get_RefreshTrace()
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmTrace.Write(Guid orgId, TraceCategory traceCategory, TraceLevel traceLevel, Int32 skipFrames, String format, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmTrace.TraceFormat(Guid orgId, TraceCategory traceCategory, TraceLevel traceLevel, String format, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Crm.LocatorCache..ctor(LocatorServiceContext locatorServiceContext)
   at Microsoft.Crm.ServerLocatorService..ctor(LocatorServiceContext locatorServiceContext)
   at Microsoft.Crm.LocatorService..ctor(ILocatorService service, LocatorServiceContext locatorServiceContext)
   at Microsoft.Crm.LocatorService..cctor()
   at Microsoft.Crm.LocatorService.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.Crm.FeatureControlChecker..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Crm.FeatureControlChecker..cctor()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Asynchronous.AsyncService..ctor(String instanceName, AsyncServiceContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Asynchronous.AsyncService.Main(String[] args) (Reporting Process:CrmAsyncService, AppDomain:D:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Server\bin\)`

and

`CrmTrace encountered an error. Additional Info:Error in LoadDeploymentSettings [LocatorService.Instance], Stack Trace :    at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmTraceSettings.Load(String traceDirectory)
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmTrace.get_RefreshTrace()
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmTrace.Write(Guid orgId, TraceCategory traceCategory, TraceLevel traceLevel, Int32 skipFrames, String format, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmTrace.TraceFormat(Guid orgId, TraceCategory traceCategory, TraceLevel traceLevel, String format, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Crm.LocatorCache..ctor(LocatorServiceContext locatorServiceContext)
   at Microsoft.Crm.ServerLocatorService..ctor(LocatorServiceContext locatorServiceContext)
   at Microsoft.Crm.LocatorService..ctor(ILocatorService service, LocatorServiceContext locatorServiceContext)
   at Microsoft.Crm.LocatorService..cctor()
   at Microsoft.Crm.LocatorService.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.Crm.FeatureControlChecker..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Crm.FeatureControlChecker..cctor()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Asynchronous.AsyncService..ctor(String instanceName, AsyncServiceContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Asynchronous.AsyncService.Main(String[] args) (Reporting Process:CrmAsyncService, AppDomain:D:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Server\bin\)`

These errors occur each time the CRM async service (re-)starts.

To find out the cause of this error, I turned on tracing and re-started the CRM async service. In the trace file of the CRM async service, the trace starts with the following lines:

```
# CRM Tracing Version 2.0
# LocalTime: 2014-08-28 09:43:21.677
# Categories: *:Verbose
# CallStackOn: No
# ComputerName: KORTRIJK
# CRMVersion: 5.0.9900.1060
# DeploymentType: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmTrace.FormatHeader(DateTime entryTime, CrmTraceSettings localSettings)
```

It appears that the CRM async service cannot determine the deployment type. The strange this is that the w3wp trace on the same machine *can* determine the deployment type. The

```
# CRM Tracing Version 2.0
# LocalTime: 2014-08-28 09:36:01.280
# Categories: *:Verbose
# CallStackOn: No
# ComputerName: KORTRIJK
# CRMVersion: 5.0.9900.1060
# DeploymentType: OnPremise
# ScaleGroup: 
# ServerRole: AppServer, AsyncService, DiscoveryService, ApiServer, HelpServer, DeploymentService, SandboxServer, DeploymentManagementTools
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I'd guess one service determines the DeploymentType from the registry while the other tries to retrieve it from the MSCRM_CONFIG db. The registry key is `ConfigSKU` at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSCRM\ but I'm at a loss where this is stored in the MSCRM_CONFIG db.

Comment: @Filburt I can confirm that the registry key is set to `ConfigSku`.  I have tried to find the correct setting in the config DB. The `AuthenticationSettings` table contains a row with configuration name is `OnPremise`, so that looks fine too.